# Export shapefile of a flow map with arrows indicating their direction in R

Tags: r, line, sp, flow-map, origin-destination

How can I insert arrows on flows and export flows map with arrows indicating their direction in R?

I know that I can use the `arrows` command of the `maptools` library to "print" an arrow in line with the flow indicating its direction, but unfortunately, the command `arrows` only works after the command `plot("object that contains the map")` run. When I export the map, of course the arrows are not exported because they are not part of the shapefile that is generated by `writeLinesShape` command.

So, is there any way this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save arrows in a shapefile. Drawing arrows depends on the software you want to import the exported shapefile. For example in ArcGIS you can simply define a symbology for the line feature to have an arrow along the direction that the linear feature is sketched.